# Company Paying Rent for Tenant

Tags: rental-property

I have a rental home in AZ. An individual wants to have the company he works for pay the rent. Is this risky for me the landlord? What would his company require from me tax-wise? Are they going to issue me a 1099? This is new territory for me and I want to cover and protect myself as a landlord.

Comment: Are you expected to invoice the company and they pay 30 days later?  Is the company signing the lease? What happens if they are late? Who pays the security deposit? Do you have a lawyer?

Comment: Note that with company rentals, it's pretty common in many areas that they pay a half year or a whole year in advance. That could be better for you, demand it if possible.

Comment: Never been a landlord, but possibly something to consider: if the employment ends (quits or fired), presumably the company will stop paying. You will presumably want safeguards that you can either get the tenant out, or make him pay.

Comment: I will not submit invoice as lease agreement will have specifics for pymt of rent and when it's due.  Company will be signing lease, however, I will request the tenant also sign the lease.  Lease agreement specifies late payments, security deposit, etc. Don't have a lawyer.  Company won't pay 1/2 or whole year's rent.  I wanted to increase rent because company will be paying but they balked at that.  Because of my hesitation,tenant has agreed to pay the rent but is now challenging me on the amt of security deposit at 1.5x rent and legal in AZ. Too many ifs for me.  Any other advice for me??